# SWIFT4: How to have two tap gestureRecognizers work together

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

NB: My gesture recognizers are not different and are in different viewControllers.

> TLDR: *How can I do to have both my tap gesture recognisers to work?*

I have created a [side menu](https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/SideMenu) from some container views and I added to it a gesture recognizer that allows me to dismiss it on tap. Then I created another ViewController where i have some textfields. Since I wanted the keyboard to dismiss on tap I even added a gesture recognizer that allows me to hide the keyboard whenever i tap the view. Now I noticed that having the gesture that hides the keyboard doesn't let my side menu hide on tap:

**SIDE MENU VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var bigContainer: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var sideMenuOpen = false
    var gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)


       gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ContainerViewController.toggleSideMenu))


    }


    @objc func toggleSideMenu() {
        if sideMenuOpen {
            sideMenuOpen = false
            sideMenuConstraint.constant = -240
        self.bigContainer.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
        } else {
            sideMenuOpen = true
           sideMenuConstraint.constant = 0
         self.bigContainer.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!)

        }
    }
```

**MAIN VIEW VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var menuOutlet: UIButton!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  let endEditingTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        endEditingTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(endEditingTapGesture)
}
 @IBAction func toggleSideMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Toggle side menu")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)

    }
}
```

I tried removing the tap gesture to hide the keyboard in my `toggleSideMenu` button but it didn't work.

Comment: So in your app user can open side menu and at the same time he/she can type too? You can try `gesture.isEnabled = false/true`.

Comment: You can open the side menu and you can close it tapping everywhere but since There’s the keyboard tap gesture I can’t close it anymore but the keyboard gesture works... Where should I do that? The gestures are in different view controllers and I can’t call the endEditing gesture in my project because it’s in the viewDidLoad

Comment: `let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dissmissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        if menuOutlet.isEnabled == true{
            tap.isEnabled = false
        } else if menuOutlet.isEnabled == false {
            tap.isEnabled = true
        }
        
        
    }
 
    @objc func dissmissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)

    }` I tried this but after I press on the side menu button it is permanently enabled

Comment: you have first hide the keyboard (if keyboard open) then close the side menu

Comment: also you add the UIKeybaord notification to check that, keyboard is hide or show

Comment: @Marybnq Please check my updated answer, is it helpful for you?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I’m telling you in a moment, I don’t have my macbook right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER** Replace with below code:

```
    var endEditingTapGesture:UIGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    endEditingTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
    endEditingTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notication:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil) //Add keyboard notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notication:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
@IBAction func toggleSideMenu(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Toggle side menu")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)

}

//Keyboard method
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notication:Notification) {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(endEditingTapGesture)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notication:Notification) {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(endEditingTapGesture)
}
```

Comment: This way when I press on the textField it opens the side menu as well

Comment: can you share a demo example if possible so that I can find where is problem?